# Reduced electric field strength in a homogenous isotropic linear dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dielectric

Griffiths says that for the electrostatic field and electric displacement to work alike, the entire space needs to be filled with the meat of the dielectric, but I'm not sure what he means when saying the whole space. Can someone elaborate on this? When exactly am I able to use this parallel between the electrostatic field and displacement?

Comment: Some context would be appreciated. What is meant by 'work alike'? Does it mean they're a scalar multiple of each other? What is meant by  'the meat of the dielectric'?

Comment: When the electric displacemebt has zero curl it "works like the electric field", in the sense that it might be just calculated directly from the free charge, and is a constsnt multiple of the electric field of the free charges.The meat here means just within the dielectric material

Comment: My concern here is that I don't know when this is true and can be used in a problem. He says that the dielectric must fill the whole spave but I think there is more to it, I'm not sure.

Comment: I can't find the words "work alike" in Griffiths.

Comment: He referred to it as a deceptive parallel, but this is really not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric displacement or electric flux density $\mathbf{D}$ is related to the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ by the constitutive relation $$\mathbf{D}  = \bar{\mathbf{\varepsilon}}\mathbf{E}$$

Where the bar above $\bar{\mathbf{ \varepsilon}}$ is used to show that it is generally a dyadic.

If $\bar{\varepsilon}$ is isotropic and constant in space and time, then $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ are related by a simple constant $\varepsilon$. Otherwise, it is not generally true.

For example, in electrostatics, the curl of the electric field is zero, i.e. $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = 0$.
However, if $\varepsilon$ varies with position, then the curl of the electric flux density is not generally zero because:
$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{D} = \nabla \times \varepsilon \mathbf{E} = \varepsilon \nabla \times \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{E} \times \nabla \varepsilon = \mathbf{E} \times \nabla \varepsilon$$

Which vanishes when $\nabla \varepsilon $ is zero, i.e. when the permittivity does not vary with position.

Comment: so can I just pick the portion of the space of interest in which the there is a linear isotropic homogeneous dielectric and assume this relation holds just inside this portion of space, like in a half-filled capacitor for instance? or is there any other subtlty?

Comment: In the case of the half-filled capacitor this would hold for the filled part and the empty part seperately, yes. As long as those assumptions are locally true for the permittivity, you can assume the electric field and the electric flux density are locally related by a constant.